# How do you review close votes for recently-asked questions?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-close

I recently earned enough reputation to review close votes. Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see many resources for learning how to review close votes. So far [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) is all I have to go on for reviewing close votes and it doesn't answer provide much guidance. I also haven't found much else about this topic in meta.

In particular, many of the questions I see in the queue are relatively new questions that haven't really had enough time to refine the question.

Maybe the question will eventually deserve to be closed but if the question has been up for a few hours or even less, and it's not blatantly off-topic, it seems unfair not to give the poster a chance to refine their question before it's closed.

On the page above, it does mention that users can "edit the question" which will cast a reopen vote, although I'm not quite sure how that works, plus it still seems like young questions deserve a bit of a grace period.

Sometimes I have marked these as leave open, but when I go back to see what other people voted, many people are voting to close them.

What is the goal here? (And are there any more detailed SO resources on what deserves to be closed?)

Comment: You definitely shouldn't consider anything else than the current quality of the question when reviewing. Age, asker, grace-period, or anything else doesn't matter. Having said that, closing is not the end of the question. It actually helps op because it prevents more down-votes on the question. They can still edit the question into shape after closure and the question can be reopened. SO expects users to post good question in first place, not to post some question and then refine them step-by-step.

Comment: @BDL closure does not prevent further downvotes. Only locking and deletion do. Now, closed questions do get less exposure, so in practice they likely get fewer upvotes than comparable open questions, but anyone with the ability to downvote who chances upon a closed question has the ability to downvote it if they please.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: You're absolutely right. Why did I think that closing prevents votes?

Comment: Ah, that is very helpful. May be useful to include that information when you expand "More" in the review queue or on the page that discusses the privilege. Or maybe the word "Close" is a bit harsh, since it implies more permanence than it actually is meant to.

Comment: If you are not sure what to do with particular question, don't vote Leave Open (or Close). Skip the question instead. Nothing bad will happen if you skip it.

Comment: a canonical reference for discussion about what @DalijaPrasnikar mentioned if you're interested in more details: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601) (there are [about 80 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/252195?lq=1) listed as linked to it just in case if you'd want to drill even deeper)